# Is there a way to push foralls past constructors when sound?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have

```
data Foo p =
    NoFoo
  | YesFoo (forall a. p a)
```

I can write

```
fromFoo :: Foo p -> Maybe (p a)
fromFoo NoFoo = Nothing
fromFoo (YesFoo p) = Just p
```

It's also possible to go the other way:

```
toFoo :: forall p.
         (forall a. Maybe (p a))
      -> Foo p
toFoo m =
  case m :: Maybe (p ()) of
    Nothing -> NoFoo
    Just _ -> YesFoo (fromJust m)
```

The `fromJust` is disgusting! `toFoo` is actually total, because parametricity ensures that `m @a` behaves exactly the same as `m @()`, but this is gross. Is there any cleaner way?

Edit: rampion pointed out that this can be written more concisely, still with `fromJust`. I just realized it can be done a bit humorously, making fun of the newbies:

```
toFoo m
  | isNothing m = NoFoo
  | otherwise = YesFoo (fromJust m)
```

The only way I see to avoid creating a thunk to apply `fromJust` is by getting super-evil:

```
toFoo Nothing = NoFoo
toFoo (Just x) = YesFoo (unsafeCoerce# x)
```

Comment: For the record, I'm guessing you're not using the signature `toFoo :: forall p. (Maybe (forall a. p a)) -> Foo p` (which would make the implementation trivial) because of the "GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism" error message.

Comment: @rampion, ah, now I understand your question. I think that's a valid question, but perhaps a slightly different one.

Comment: @rampion Isn't the question equivalent to `(forall a. Maybe (p a)) -> Maybe (forall a. p a)`? Not the type in your comment

Comment: I have a feeling there might exist datatypes `T` for which `forall a. T a` is not equivalent to `T (forall a. a)`. Struggling to come up with an example though, so I may well be wrong.

Comment: Actually, yeah: `newtype Pred a = Pred { runPred :: a -> Bool }`. `forall a. Pred a` is a polymorphic predicate that works on any `a`, but `Pred (forall a. a)` (let's pretend for a moment that that's a valid type) is a monomorphic predicate that only works on polymorphic values. So there's no general recipe for pushing the `forall`s around like that. Any answer you're gonna get is going to have to be specific to `Maybe` (or at least some part of its interface, like `Functor`).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, that's an example where it can't be pulled out; it can be pushed in just fine. Note also the "when sound" in the title.

Comment: Ah, of course. Keen to see if this question gets an answer!

Comment: “because parametricity ensures that `m @a` behaves exactly the same as `m @()`” – true, but only if `a` is completely unconstrained. _You_ know that, but I don't suppose GHC has a special case of universal quantification witnessing that free theorem, hence it's a piece of information the compiler has no right to exploit – you must explicitly circumvent the type system to get access to it, as you do with `fromJust` or `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it must have *some* of that machinery to make @rampion's expression (and my `unsafeCoerce#` one) work as written. It instantiates `a` to `Any` to perform the pattern match, knowing that it doesn't matter which type it picks.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with so far still uses `fromJust`, but it's simpler:

```
toFoo :: forall p.
         (forall a. Maybe (p a))
      -> Foo p
toFoo Nothing = NoFoo
toFoo m = YesFoo $ fromJust m
```

Comment: Another disgusting option is to match on the `Just` constructor and then `unsafeCoerce` its contents to generalize.